issues updating an apache2 module to work on Arm64 on macos
I've been asked to recompile a working module to work on an arm64 based macos, ie a new M3 processor.
It was originally written in C++ and only used a makefile to compile the source code.
I never compiled that, but in that version I cannot see how it links to a library for httpd, or apr or aprutil.
So, I setup a dev environment:
I downloaded httpd-2.4.62
dropped apr and apr-util into srclib

used macports to get an updated ssl installed...

Set config settings:

./configure \
--with-included-apr \
--with-ssl=/opt/local/libexec/openssl3 \
--enable-ssl \
--enable-so \
--enable-modules=most \
--enable-mods-shared=all \
--prefix=/usr/local/apache2 

which appears to have compiled fully.
Looking around it seems maybe I need to use apxs to compile this module these days?
but doing so, I get an error message
libtool:   error: '/usr/local/apache2/lib/libaprutil-1.la' is not a convenience library 

So, what is wrong? is it compiled incorrectly, or some other issue I am unaware of.
So, I'm wondering whether to find a lib to link to directly in the original C++ makefile,
or, find some resolution to this latter error, of the file not being a convenience library.
Any suggestions of what I might do to resolve this?
Or just some link to a website about how to build such a thing?
Thanks in advance for any help

That configure script is of the module you're trying to build? Or is it from httpd? I would use an httpd from your package manager and focus on the module, really.

The configure is for httpd... You may be right in directing me away from configuring the httpd, and just concentrate on the module... but would that then overcome my linking issues I wonder? Originally I was just keeping it totally separate from any proper installs, but moved away from that idea.
